# How to efficiently seach key in nested map (C++)?

Tags: c++, nested, multimap

I have a nested multimap - map structure like:

```
typedef std::vector< struct > dataVector_t;
typedef std::map< int, dataVector_t > intMap_t;    
typedef std::multimap< int1, intMap_t > intMultiMap_t
```

What is the most efficient way to search for the innerKey in the inner map?

Here is my current approach. It works, but it takes too long.

```
    intMap_t getInnerMap( const intMultiMap_t & outerMap, const int outerKey )
    {
    intMap_t returnMap; 

    if ( !outerMap.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto outerIt= outerMap.lower_bound( outerKey ); outerIt!= outerMap.upper_bound( outerKey ); outerIt++ )
        {
            auto innerMap= outerIt->second;

            if ( !innerMap.empty() )
            {
                for ( auto innerIt= innerMap.begin(); innerIt!= innerMap.end(); innerIt++ )
                {
                    returnMap.emplace( innerIt->first, innerIt->second);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnMap;
}

dataVector_t MapData::getDataVector( const intMultiMap_t & outerMap, const int outerKey, const int innerKey ) 
{
    dataVector_t returnValue {};

    auto innerMap = getInnerMap( outerMap, outerKey );

    if ( innerMap.size() > 0 )
    {
        auto innerIter = innerMap.find( innerKey);
        if ( innerIter == innerMap.end() ) // innerKey not found
        {
            innerIter = innerMap.lower_bound( innerKey); //so find key just after innerKey
            if ( innerIter != innerMap.begin() )
            {
                --innerIter ; //find key just before innerKey
            }
        }

        returnValue = innerIter->second; 

    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I've also looked at using equal_range to identify the range of my innerMap, then use lower_bound to find the innerKey, but it seems I have to loop through element by element until I find the innerKey.

Comment: Are you limited to C++03? `std::unordered_map` could be faster.

Comment: If the goal is to do it "efficiently", then this is the wrong container or data structure; because there is no other way than to do it iteratively, in this fashion.

Comment: What do you need this nested data-structure for? What is the problem it's supposed to solve? What is your program doing?

Comment: What this `getInnerMap` supposed to do? This condition `outerIt!= outerMap.upper_bound( outerKey )` in for loop is a code smell.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'm voting to close as "Seek debugging help ..." since there is no description what it suppose to do and how to reproduce it.

Comment: @Marek R, I am using C++11.

Comment: The application is retrieving map-based information for a self-driving car application. The first int is the path ID and the second int it the offset (longitudinal distance) along that path and the data vector is information about the road at that offset and path ID. We have a graph based implementation on other projects which is more efficient, but for this project I am stuck with this data structure.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik  What data structure would you recommend?

Comment: There is insufficient information to be able to determine the appropriate container. The appropriate container depends on all the requirements. The key to selecting the right container is to understand what all the requirements are, and what each of the different containers in the C++ library are for. Quite often no single container will be appropriate, and it becomes necessary to combine multiple containers together, like what's already done here; but this is not the optimal combination. Whatever's the right combination, this is something only you have all the information needed to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way to search for the innerKey in the inner map?

Generally, the most efficient way to search for a key in `std::map` is to use the `find` member function:

```
auto innerIt = outerIt->second.find(innerKey);
```

Comment: So I think this would be essentially what I am doing...create a stand-alone map from the nested multimap - map structure then search using find(), lower_bound() or upper_bound().

Comment: @ScottP Why do you create a copy of the inner map?

Comment: So I can search for the innerKey using lower_bound().

Comment: @ScottP why not search through `outerIt`  like in my example?

Comment: I thought find() could only be used on the container itself, not an iterator pointing to the container? When I try to implement this example it will not compile. Maybe I am doing something wrong. If I searching using find on the outer container, it finds the int in the outer multimap instead of the int in the inner map.

Comment: @ScottP You can indirect through an iterator to access the referred element. In my example, the indirecting member access operator `->` does that.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for but I cannot get it to compile. The compiler keeps telling me find is not a member of outerIt. Is this something new since C++11?

Comment: @ScottP not new. I just forgot that the element of the map is a pair of key and value, rather than just the value. Answer fixed.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see this sooner.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. I think it is because my outer map is actually a multimap. As a result, each multimap only has one map nested inside it.